# Optimisation of writing join table records

Tags: join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgis, rgeo

The application is based on PostGIS and stores data using RGeo's simple_mercator_factory.

Polygon records are created and associations with points are static (i.e. don't need updating).  To reduce overhead on postGIS calculations, it makes sense to populate a join table with the points belonging to a polygon and the conduct searches on an indexed join table using bTree (in lieu of rTree).

The problem is efficient creation of the join records.  At present:

```
@line_string1 = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory.line_string([@point_a, @point_b, @point_c, @point_d])
@points = Point.all
@points_in ||= []
@points.each do |point|
  this_point = point.lonlat
  @this_poly = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory.polygon(@line_string1)
  if this_point.intersects?(@this_poly)
      @add_point = pointpolygon.new(:point_id => point.id, :polygon_id => @polygon.id)
      @add_point.save
  end
end
```

The query plan is acceptable

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "point".* FROM "points"
                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on points  (cost=0.00..210.10 rows=8110 width=99)
(1 row)
```

However, the `@add_point` function is clocking  between 14 and 16 ms.  For a set of 83 records, we're looking a something like 1.6 seconds.  But the totals **do not** match up:
`Completed 302 Found in 7796.9ms (ActiveRecord: 358.5ms)`
Running a separate method that does the same query plan (and times), without writing join records completes in
`Completed 200 OK in 1317.5ms (Views: 49.8ms | ActiveRecord: 64.0ms)`
Two questions arise.  More mundanely, why has the total ballooned so much - I was expecting something like 3 seconds (1.6 + 1.3) - aside from development mode conditions?

But more to the point, is there a way to wrap off the writing of the join table records to a separate thread (after_update?) in a more efficient manner (considering 1000 records could to be written...)

Comment: Why don't you populate the table using a single query that looks for points intersecting the polygon?

Comment: As stated above, the relationship is static: once established it does not required refreshing.  Since GIS searches are more computational intensive (moreso for geographic), I do want to test this design (it is a form of logical caching) vs your suggestion.  The goal is fast answers to queries with consideration for scaling (creation of records does not have to necessarily be fast)

Comment: I'm not talking about seeking intersecting point every time when you select, I'm talking about filling your pointpolygon table with one query instead of one row at a time.

Comment: That observation is correct.  I have not found the right syntaxic  combination between ruby, rgeo and postgis. Am willing to consider stright postGIS querying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jakub correctly points out, a method for extracting all the valid points in one shot:

```
def valid_points
  Point.order("id").joins("INNER JOIN points ON points.id=#{id} AND st_contains(polygon.poly, points.lonlat)").all
end
```

which then invoked by the controller

```
  @valid_points = @polygon.valid_points
  @valid_points.each do |point|
    @add_point = Pointpolygon.new(:point_id => point.id, :polygon_id => @polygon.id)
    @add_point.save
  end
```

yields much nicer response times.  For test cases up to 1000 matches, the creation time per record creation is between 1.2 and 1.4 ms in development mode.